# Calculate row on datatable based on info from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Unsure how to look for documentation.

I have managed to get the work done but not sure how to look for the operation I am trying to do and/or if there is a better way to do it.

I have a list of variables by type. For each type of variable there is a set of "pure" variable name that I have named **seed**

Example:
Seeds:

```
> seed
   S_TYPE    NAMESS
1:      A      var1
2:      A      var2
3:      B      var3
4:      B    var1_1
5:      C     var_3
6:      C var_1_1_1
7:      C   var_2_1
```

List of variables:

```
   S_TYPE       NAMESS_MOD
1:      A       A_var1_2_1
2:      A       A_var1_3_3
3:      A         A_var2_4
4:      B         B_var1_1
5:      B          B_var_3
6:      C   C_var_1_1_1_LN
7:      C C_var_1_1_1_PLUS
```

I am looking to get the "seed" for each variable. The problem is that S_TYPE comes into play and there can be different types with different seeds

Example:
Seeds

```
   S_TYPE    NAMESS
1:      A      var1
2:      A      var2
3:      B      var3
4:      B    var1_1
5:      C     var_3
6:      C var_1_1_1
7:      C   var_2_1
```

VARIABLES

```
   S_TYPE       NAMESS_MOD
1:      A       A_var1_2_1
2:      A       A_var1_3_3
3:      A         A_var2_4
4:      B         B_var1_1
5:      B          B_var_3
6:      C   C_var_1_1_1_LN
7:      C C_var_1_1_1_PLUS
```

Depending on S_TYPE there are different seeds
My goal is to get this result:

```
   S_TYPE       NAMESS_MOD real_seed
1:      A       A_var1_2_1      var1
2:      A       A_var1_3_3      var1
3:      A         A_var2_4      var2
4:      B         B_var1_1    var1_1
5:      B          B_var_3      <NA>
6:      C   C_var_1_1_1_LN var_1_1_1
7:      C C_var_1_1_1_PLUS var_1_1_1
```

I have used this code because I found no other way:

```
seed <- data.table(S_TYPE = c("A","A","B","B", "C","C","C"),
                    NAMESS = c("var1","var2","var3","var1_1",
                               "var_3","var_1_1_1","var_2_1")
                    );seed
modifiedseed <- data.table(S_TYPE = c("A","A","A","B","B", "C","C"),
                           NAMESS_MOD = c("A_var1_2_1","A_var1_3_3","A_var2_4",
                                      "B_var1_1","B_var_3",
                                      "C_var_1_1_1_LN","C_var_1_1_1_PLUS")
                           );modifiedseed
split_seed <- split(seed, seed[,S_TYPE])
split_modifiedseed <- split(modifiedseed, modifiedseed[,S_TYPE])
split_modifiedseed$A[, real_seed := str_extract( split_modifiedseed$A[, NAMESS_MOD], str_c( split_seed$A[, NAMESS], collapse= "|"))]
split_modifiedseed$B[, real_seed := str_extract( split_modifiedseed$B[, NAMESS_MOD], str_c( split_seed$B[, NAMESS], collapse= "|"))]
split_modifiedseed$C[, real_seed := str_extract( split_modifiedseed$C[, NAMESS_MOD], str_c( split_seed$C[, NAMESS], collapse= "|"))
rbindlist(split_modifiedseed)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using a `regex_join` from the `fuzzyjoin`-package
I used the `data.table`-package just to read in the sample data and create data.frames. no need for it when you have already got you data in `data.frame`-format.

**create sample data**

```
library( data.table )

seed <- data.table::fread("S_TYPE    NAMESS
A      var1
A      var2
B      var3
B    var1_1
C     var_3
C var_1_1_1
C   var_2_1")

VARIABLES <-  data.table::fread("S_TYPE       NAMESS_MOD
A       A_var1_2_1
A       A_var1_3_3
A         A_var2_4
B         B_var1_1
B          B_var_3
C   C_var_1_1_1_LN
C C_var_1_1_1_PLUS")

#create data.frames
data.table::setDF( seed )
data.table::setDF( VARIABLES )
```

**code with regex_join**

```
library( fuzzyjoin )
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join( VARIABLES, seed, by = c( S_TYPE = "S_TYPE", NAMESS_MOD = "NAMESS" ))
```

**output**

```
#   S_TYPE.x       NAMESS_MOD S_TYPE.y    NAMESS
# 1        A       A_var1_2_1        A      var1
# 2        A       A_var1_3_3        A      var1
# 3        A         A_var2_4        A      var2
# 4        B         B_var1_1        B    var1_1
# 5        B          B_var_3     <NA>      <NA>
# 6        C   C_var_1_1_1_LN        C var_1_1_1
# 7        C C_var_1_1_1_PLUS        C var_1_1_1
```